# create an index without locking the DB

Tags: mysql, rake, ruby-on-rails

I have a table with 10+ million rows.  I need to create an index on a single column, however, the index takes so long to create that I get locks against the table.

It may be important to note that the index is being created as part of a 'rake db:migrate' step... I'm not adverse to creating the index manually if that will work.

UPDATE: I suppose I should have mentioned that this a write often table.

Comment: Locks are fine. Are you getting timeouts or deadlocks?

Comment: Locks are not fine.  That's the complaint.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: @Richard, if you update MySQL to a version >5.1.7 it looks like you can create an index w/o locking the DB.  I haven't tried it, I was lucky enough to be able to schedule a short down-time window (during an install) where I could apply the indexes.

Comment: Try facebook OSC, or Percona Toolkit if you are using MySQL. We are very very happey with Percona toolkit for online schema changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL NDBCLUSTER engine can create index online without locking the writes to the table. However, the most widely used InnoDB engine does not support this feature. Another free and open source DB Postgres supports 'create index concurrently'.

Comment: 'create index concurrently' was added in version 8.2 or there abouts.

Comment: Recently we have been using Percona toolkit to do online schema changes without locking tables with InnoDB.

Answer (score 2):

you can prevent the blockage with something like this (pseudo-code):

```
create table temp like my_table;
update logger to log in temp;
alter table my_table add index new_index;
insert into my_table select * from temp;
update logger to log in my_table;
drop table temp
```

Where logger would be whatever adds rows/updates to your table in regular use(ex.: php script). This will set up a temporary table to use while the other one updates.

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned that this a write often table. So a temp table is going to be hard but not impossible to implement.  Just a bit less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure that the index is created *before* the records are inserted. That way, the index will also be filled during the population of the table. Although that will take longer, at least it will be ready to go when the rake task is done.

Comment: Most indexes are created this way; however; contrary to popular belief the wizards at Oracle and at Microsoft are constantly telling their DBAs to rebuild their indexes when performance starts to lag. Also in some ETL cases it's actually more efficient to index later.